# How do I add touch event to the CCNode in CocosSharp?

Tags: c#, monogame, cocossharp

I have a layer:

```
public class MenuItemsLayer : CCLayer
{
    protected override void AddedToScene()
    {
        base.AddedToScene();

        var quitItem = new CCLabel("QUIT", "fonts/MarkerFelt", 22, CCLabelFormat.SpriteFont);
        (...)
        this.AddEventListener(this.addQuitItemTouchListener(), quitItem);
        this.AddChild(quitItem);
    }

    private CCEventListenerTouchOneByOne addQuitItemTouchListener()
    {
        var touchListener = new CCEventListenerTouchOneByOne();
        touchListener.OnTouchEnded = (touch, args) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("touched");
        };

        return touchListener;
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to "quitItem". I'm adding CCEventListenerTouchOneByOne to it with the hope, that it will do something I want. In this case it should write "touched"  in the output if element is touched. Unfortunantely, nothing happens, also breakpoint is never hit.

Basic problem - I'd like to add touch event to the CCNode. How?

Answer (score 1):

// class variable
    CCLabel quitItem;

```
// In AddedToScene
var touchListener =  new CCEventListenerTouchAllAtOnce();
touchListener.OnTouchBegan = this.OnTouchesBegan;
AddEventListener(touchListener,this);


// Handler

void OnTouchesBegan(List<CCTouch> touches, CCEvent touchEvent)
{
    if ( quitItem.BoundingBoxTransformedToWorld.ContainsPoint(touches[0].Location ))
            {
                // print message here
            }

}
```